# Is there a way to find out which stocks are scheduled to be delisted?

Tags: united-states, stocks, trading, stock-exchanges

Often there are buyouts or corporate actions or other reasons that cause a stock to be removed from an exchange (delisted).  Given a specific company and specific situation, it's often possible to find a report submitted to the exchange or published by the company that indicates that a stock will cease trading on that exchange sometime in the future.  Reports I've seen often do not include a specific date for delisting.

Given an exchange (NYSE, NASDAQ, AMEX, etc), is there a schedule or calendar that specifies when specific stocks, currently still on the exchange but with a future plan of being delisted, will no longer be traded or become de-listed?

Comment: Note that delisting from a major exchange doesn't mean that the stock is untradeable - it can operate as an OTC stock for years (and is still tradeable).  You should pay very careful attention to the wording of any takeovers, intention to delist etc.  There are obvious signs a company might be delisted by the exchange: inability to file timely reports, compulsory acquisition of shares in a takeover, limited liquidity, low market cap, low trading price, limited number of shareholders, foreign-domicile entities wanting to reduce their reporting burden, or "Elon Musk" as chairman etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is timely since 4 days ago, one of my stocks announced the takeover of another one of my stocks and I have been searching for the date without success.

The only resource that I know of is the NASDAQ's list of "Issues Pending Suspension or Delisting" and it doesn't go very far forward in time.  From the site:

> Each trading day, Nasdaq publishes a list of Nasdaq issues that are pending suspension or delisting. An issue will appear on this list the first trading day after the issuer provides Nasdaq with notification of its intent to voluntarily delist. An issue will also appear on this list if it has been suspended for failure to meet continued listing requirements or due to other events such as expiration, redemption, or acquisition of the security.
>
> Issues will remain on this list until the first business day after the issue is delisted. An issue is delisted 10 calendar days from the date the Form 25, Notification of Removal from Listing and/or Registration, is filed with the Securities and Exchange Commission. These forms can be viewed by entering the company's name or the issue's symbol on the Commission's web site at http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html.

https://listingcenter.nasdaq.com/IssuersPendingSuspensionDelisting.aspx

Perhaps someone may know of and will post a better resource.

Comment: Using the searchedgar, I can put in "25-NSE" and get a nice list, but alas, there's no time between the form showing there and the delisting action.